# Swift Saving a Variable

Tags: ios, swift

I need help saving a variable well... two variables.
here is my viewcontroller file.I tried NSUser but people said that it's only supposed to be used for settings user data etc.Any help is nice :)
Thanks

```
import UIKit
var wreath = 0
var box = 0




class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var YouHaveB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var YouHaveW: UILabel!

@IBAction func Wreaths(sender: AnyObject) {
    wreath += 1
    YouHaveW.text = "You Have \(wreath) Wreaths"

}
@IBAction func Boxes(sender: AnyObject) {
    box += 1
    YouHaveB.text = "You Have \(box) Boxes"
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with adding these to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I tried but I didn't work :(

Comment: Then update your posting show the code that doesn't work

Comment: You can also consider if using the restoration api will be more appropriate: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html

Comment: Could I do this without using NSUserDeaults or the api?

Comment: What have you got against defaults? ;-)  Its literally just a few lines to save and the same to restore. You can save it to a file instead if you really insist on doing so. THere's no easier way then defaults and if you think you shouldn't use them then please post a link to a reference saying its bad to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setInteger(wreath, forKey: "wreath")
defaults.setInteger(box, forKey: "box")
```

To fetch:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let wreath = defaults. integerForKey("wreath")
{
   // do something with wreath value here
}

if let box = defaults. integerForKey("box")
{
   // do something with box value here
}
```

Comment: in iOS 8 and on, you should not call synchronize() in most situations

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` can be used for storing anything from the user name to user settings. It is very simple to use.

To set value simple call:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setValue(wreath, forKey: "wreaths")
defaults.setValue(box, forKey: "box")
```

To get these values You need to call:

```
let default = NSUserDefaults.standarduserDefaults()
let box = defaults.valueForKey("box")
let wreath = defaults.valueForKey("wreath")
```

Hope this helps. :)